# Using fopen() fputcsv() fclose() VS. print() and redirect display into file

Tags: php, performance, debian

## Context :

I'm programming a PHP script, which performs export from database and writes the data into a CSV file.
The script will run on a Debian9 server, with PHP 5.6.40.
The server hosts a big website using Magento 1.9, with at least 100 customers performing actions at almost every moment, so I want to reduce the impact of the script.
The script will be launch by SSH in a CLI.

**EDIT :**
In my particular case, I don't need to escape quote or anything, I can put raw data directly into the output file.
Please find below some data exemple :

```
"100015876"
"1"
"1.12"
"FAKE-SKU"
"2019-12-20"
```

I except the file containing at least 45k lines.

## Question :

Which way is the most "memory-friendly" between those two :

**First one**
*Script*

```
$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');  
///Some logic  
fputcsv($fp, $data,";");   
fclose($fp);
```

*CLI*

```
php myScript.php
```

**Second one**
*Script*

```
//Some logic
print("$data1;$data2;...;$dataX");
```

*CLI*

```
php myScript.php > file.csv
```

## Guess :

I guess the second one is better, but I can't (don't know how) run proper tests.
If anyone can explain me how to test this (and if/why one is better than the other), it would be very nice of him/her.

Comment: The second option is not complete though. You would need to quote some values, escape quotes in the strings etc. `fputcsv()` does that for you so that would def. be the preferred way. Are you currently having issues with performance/memory with the current code? If not, just stick to `fputcsv()` until you can see it's a bottle neck.

Comment: I would expect there to be very little difference between the 2, but `fputcsv` does more than just print the values.

Comment: I've edited my initial post. As you can see, in the raw data, string are already between double quote and I know for sure that there is not need to transform it.

Comment: The question still remains. Why? Are you currently experiencing issues with your code (while using `fputcsv()`?) Or is this just some premature optimization? Do some profiling on both ways and check which fits the best. If you do some search, there are plenty of examples about profiling your scripts.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Last time I did something similar, the dataset was way bigger and yes, I had some issues with `fputcsv()`. This time, I try to prevent performance/memory issues. (Last time, the only way to proceed the request was to split it into smaller ones, but it was very time and effort consuming).

Comment: We've pointed out some of the main differences. It's up to you do decide which fits you the best. Test both ways and profile the scripts and see the performance differences. There are plenty of tools to help with that. One of them is [xdebug](https://xdebug.org/docs/profiler)

Comment: OK, thanks for having pointed out main differences. I will run some tests with xdebug. If I found something interesting, I will post it here. Again, thanks a lot.